# I mistakenly revealed the name of the new company to HR of the current company

Tags: resignation, company

I am working as a team leader in the current company and have resigned as I got a new opportunity, but during the HR meeting I mistakenly revealed the name of the new company. Can this affect me in any way?

Answer (score 53):

> So is this can affect me in any way?

In my country, once it's a done deal and the contracts are signed and notice was given, "Oh you leave? Where are you going?" is a perfectly valid question among colleagues and it's normal to just tell. HR won't ask out of professional courtesy, but they only need to grab a coffee at the watercooler to find out if they wanted to.

For some paperwork it would even be legally required for one company to contact the other, although since that part is optional, most new employers just give you the benefit of the doubt and don't ask for this type of paperwork.

So, in my country this knowledge is not guarded. Everybody knows through the grapevine.

The only consequence is that other colleagues that would like to work at your new company too will ask you for a reference or advice how to get hired.

---

On the other hand, I have seen so many posts here where the mood and laws in general are so toxic in certain countries, that if your work life is a miserable hell in general, I'm sure that this piece of information can be used against you, too. But I guess that goes for *any* piece of information there.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the apparent contradiction in this paragraph: "For some paperwork it would even be legally required for one company to contact the other, although since that part is optional, [...]" How can it be both "legally required" and "optional"?

Comment: @V2Blast The minimum number of paid days of is regulated by law. Most employers just say "I will treat you as if you had no prior job this year, is that okay with you", but if the employee insists, then the employer cannot just make up a number, but has to get confirmation how much paid days of the employee already took with other employers this year.

Comment: As there is basically no way for the employee to gain anything from this without super weird exceptional circumstances, I have never heard of anyone insisting... but in theory that could happen and there's laws and regulations for it. I have also never heard of the employer to make use of it, because it's more paperwork to find out the number of days, than just granting them by default.

Comment: In the Netherlands, this works differently: vacation days are pro-rated for the remainder of the year based on your starting date. If you had any outstanding vacation days at your previous employer, that employer will pay those out, and - on your request - provide you with a declaration of the number of days you had remaining at the end of your contract. Your new employer is - when you ask for it - legally required to give you that number of days as **unpaid** vacation days (unpaid as your previous employer already paid for them), those unpaid days expire after six months.

Answer (score 16):

> So is this can affect me in any way?

In theory it shouldn't.

You are already leaving, hopefully in good terms, and I presume you already have accepted a contract/offer with the other company, so there are few things they could do to "affect" you in any way.

Perhaps it was a bit awkward the moment you mistakenly disclosed it, but not something to die for I'm sure.

Answer (score 7):

This is very unlikely to be a problem.

In most cases, your new company will contact the HR department of your existing company. This could be for a reference (not a character reference, just confirmation that you worked there with dates), or for paperwork related to tax (or pensions, in some countries). So HR would have found out the name of your new company very soon anyway.

Comment: OP hasn't stated their country, but this is pretty standard in the UK

Comment: @PeterH yes indeed --- my experience is primarily in the UK but have tried to give as country-neutral an answer as possible. (After all, people in any country might ask this question.)

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is theoretically possible that HR or anyone else from your old company will use this information to badmouth you at your new company or make your life difficult in some other way.

However, unless there is a specific reason to think otherwise, I just always assume that people will behave normal and not do things like that. So in the past I never kept my new employer a secret when switching jobs. If you have a LinkedIn profile and update it, people from your old company will find the details about your new job soon anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I worked in a few European countries and this has never been an issue, usually openly discussed where my next job would be.

However there might be a few points to take into account:

- are you violating any rules in your contract? (Perhaps working for a competitor might be sued) if this is the case you might need to see what are the options in your country with your contract
- do you have NDAs valid past your termination date? If this is the case your old company might just “keep an eye” on the matter, not sure how.
- do you have some bad relationships in the old place which might have an influence on how you are perceived in the new place? Are you leaving any skeletons in the wardrobe?

As many stated: it’s unusual to rollback a done deal, and in the end it’s a business so they will keep you or not depending on how much value you contribute to.

However you probably have a probation period and if, for example, you have a weak spot of being a slacker (which is known to your old company)... somebody with influence and connections might want to give an heads up to a “friend” working in the new company, and speaking about you they might say:

- “yeah he is a good guy, but might slack a bit”

So if you have weak spots, try to work on them as much as you can, because those might be under a magnifying glass for various reasons.

Which is a good idea regardless of how any of this totally made up situations might or not happens to you.

Good luck!

Comment: The one post that remembered the all important expressions "contract" and "NDA".

Comment: If working at the new company violated the OP's contract or NDA the OP has set himself up for disaster. It would be extremely foolish  to hope that the old company just wouldn't find out where his new job was.